Definition of covariant Hessian
I read the paper and on page two, it says that a linear function $A(t)$ is the covariant Hessian of a function $f$. Can anyone give me a definition of the covariant Hessian? I couldn't find anything in my research or maybe I missed it.

Would it be possible to get a reference to the said paper ?

@P.Quinton Oh sorry,  I forgot it.
